# RegEx for strings that do not both start and end with 2 open and closed curly braces

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to come up with a PHP regex that matches any strings *except* strings which have two open curly braces at the start as well as two closed curly braces at the end.

So anything other than specifically:

```
{{someString}}
```

The string can have no braces, as long as it's not 2 open and 2 closed at the start and end of the string.

So far my best attempt has been

```
^(?!{{).+(?!}})$
```

But I later realized that this doesn't match a string like `{{x` (because it starts with `{{`); I do want that string to match, just not something like `{{x}}`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The examples you show doesn't ALL start with '{{' and doesn't ALL end with '}}'

Comment: didn't get that.

Comment: Are you sure your last paragraph regarding "should match" is consistent with your first sentence? That is, aren't you seeking to match the second list and fail the first list? In other words, why not use `^{{.*}}$` which matches the second list (e.g. `{{...}}` etc) and fails on the first and filter anything matching that rather than the opposite? Also, what's your PHP code like or what are you [trying to achieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguous wording 'filters out'. I meant 'doesn't match'. The last paragraph is what i want

Comment: Curly braces are special characters in regex. Maybe you should try escaping them

Comment: $validations['parameter_custom_value'] = array('required', 'regex:/^(?!{{).+(?!}})$/');

Comment: "*I want only string that BOTH start with {{ and end with }} So, string that it should match are {{...}*" these two sentences contradict each other, as your example has 2 braces at the start and end, then your examples sometimes only have one at the start or end. Your final paragraph is contradictory too - "*string that should fail are {{...}}*" this string is exactly like your initial example. Can you clarify how many braces need to be on each end, and how many don't?

Comment: @James thanks for pointing my mistake. To clarify, I will accept any string that is NOT like {{..}}

Comment: So would you accept a string without any braces?

Comment: yes, I will accept strings without braces also, like ABC

Comment: `'~^(?!{{.*}}$).*$~s'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
^(?!{{.*}}$)
```

to match anything that's *not* matched by

```
^{{.*}}$
```

Comment: doesn't match {{a}

Comment: @Ravi: Why not?

Comment: The problem is there's no capturing group. I think you actually want `^(?!{{.+}})(.*)$`

Comment: @Nick: Why does there need to be a capturing group?

Comment: Otherwise there is nothing to match so no match will be reported. Try removing the capturing group from the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/4KvuNe/3) and you will see it reports that the regex doesn't match anything.

Comment: @Nick: Are you saying that the OP doesn't just need the regex to match or not-match (boolean result), but also needs the matched substring to cover the entire string? If so, that doesn't require a capture-group; (s)he can just append `.*`.

Comment: My point was that without anything after the negative lookahead, it seems to always return not-match. I agree it doesn't have to be a capture group, it could be just `.*`.

Comment: @Nick: The problem is that your point is wrong (as is the OP's comment) -- https://regex101.com/r/hA7H6h/1 clearly shows a match at the start of the `{{a}` line -- so I'm trying to find a not-wrong point that you might have meant instead. :-/

Comment: You are right. I missed the mark at the beginning of the string. Sorry for wasting your time. :-(

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. I have compensated.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I will go with Nick's answer, (  I added a $ at the end of the negative lookahead group, otherwise it will reject {{abc}}d   )

Answer (score 0):

Just take the problem from the other end...
We know exactly what shouldn't "pass"... And the rule is simple:

```
{{whatever or nothing between double curly brackets}}
```

So why not try to match that simple rule and deduct the result?

The string is **OK** when there is no match!

Paste the code below in [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/):

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Strings 0 to 5 should pass and the rest should fail.</h1>";

// Should pass
$string[0] = "test";
$string[1] = "{test";
$string[2] = "test}";
$string[3] = "{test}";
$string[4] = "{{test}";
$string[5] = "{test}}";

// Should fail
$string[6] = "{{test}}";
$string[7] = "{{test}}}";
$string[8] = "{{{test}}";
$string[9] = "{{{test}}}";
$string[10] = "{{}}";

$pattern = "/[\{]{2}.*[\}]{2}/";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($string);$i++){
    echo $i." - String is: <b>".$string[$i]."</b><br>";
    // --------
    preg_match($pattern,$string[$i],$matches);
    if($matches==null){
        echo "<span class='pass'>That string is ok.</span><br>";
    }else{
        echo "<span class='fail'>That string is NOT ok.</span><br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
<style>
    .pass{
        color:green;
    }
    .fail{
        color:red
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this blacklisting approach elsewhere. But in this situation since I am forced to use Laravel 5.4's regex validation, I have to go with a whitelisting approach